# Idiomatic way to compare a [c_char; N] with a given hardcoded string

Tags: string, rust, ffi

I am iterating over a bunch of null-terminated C strings of type `[c_char; 256]` and have to compare them against a handful of hardcoded values and ended up with the following monstrosity:

```rust
available_instance_extensions.iter().for_each(|extension| {
    if unsafe { CStr::from_ptr(extension.extension_name.as_ptr()) }
        .to_str()
        .unwrap()
        == "VK_KHR_get_physical_device_properties2"
    {
        log::info!("Got it!");
    }
});
```

Is there any idiomatic and sane approach to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of [Rust 1.77](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2024/03/21/Rust-1.77.0.html#c-string-literals), you can do `c"VK_KHR_get_physical_device_properties2"`.

---

You can create [`CStr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.CStr.html) string using:

```rust
CStr::from_bytes_with_nul(b"VK_KHR_get_physical_device_properties2\0")
  .unwrap();
```

Also, unsafe variant:

```rust
unsafe {
  CStr::from_bytes_with_nul_unchecked(b"VK_KHR_get_physical_device_properties2\0")
};
```

But I advice using [cstr](https://crates.io/crates/cstr) crate, this will allow faster and shorter code:

```rust
use cstr::cstr;

let result = unsafe { CStr::from_bytes_with_nul_unchecked(&extension.extension_name[..]) };
let expected = cstr!("VK_KHR_get_physical_device_properties2");
assert_eq!(result, expected);
```

Comment: Your newest edit using `CStr::from_bytes_with_nul_unchecked(&extension.extension_name)` is incompatible with the following error: `expected &[u8], found &[i8; 256]` thus I am still sticking with `from_ptr` and comparing against the result of `cstr!`

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic just keep using `from_ptr` if you want, same thing, `&extension.extension_name[..]` should work. Without having a MCVE it's more hard to make a compile ready answer.

Comment: Ah the addition of `[..]` might work, I will check that later.

Comment: As of Rust 1.77, this can be substituted by `c"VK_KHR_get_physical_device_properties2"`.